# how to get response from a remote server by using curl command through proxy?

Tags: linux

Please give a simple syntax for making a curl command that will connect to the remote server through proxy......

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -x my-proxy:8080 www.bbc.co.uk
```

Try here for more details: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html